# USB headset fails to install on Windows 7

Tags: usb, drivers

I am using an USB headset "Sennheiser PC35", it installs automatically on Windows XP, and the "Drivers" area on manufacturer site also says that it should install automaticaly so no driver is required.

However... on Windows 7 Pro (64bit I think) it says that the USB device failed to install correctly when I plug the USB cable, in device manager I see it as "USB Composite device" with an exclamation mark and details are "This device cannot start. (Code 10)", trying to update driver automatically or from online says it is already latest driver.

I tried all USB slots.
Some users suggested I leave computer turned off and power unplugged for a while, I tried that too and I turned it on without any other usb plugged in. No effect.

Edit: I also tried the [Vista 32 bit firmware update](http://www.senncom.com/comm/home_en.nsf/root/service_faqs_pc-usb-headsets_windows-vista_download) many articles refer to, but that one doesn't work for me on Win 7 pro 64bit.

Comment: Since this is a "Windows" question, not a programming question, I've voted to move it to Super User. Hopefully you will get better help there. :)

Comment: I used Google for you: http://www.digital-transition.com/archives/2010/giving-new-life-to-my-sennheiser-pc-35-usb-headset/

Comment: I found multiple articles mentioning to try the Vista 32 bit firmware update, but on my Windows 7 64 bit I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the explanations mentioned on most topics about this...

The fix is to run the [firmware update](http://www.senncom.com/comm/home_en.nsf/root/service_faqs_pc-usb-headsets_windows-vista_download) **on any machine**, like on windows XP for example, it will update the software/firmware inside the actual device, then when plugged to Windows 7 it will work by default.